# Wallpaper automatically blurring after a while

Tags: samsung, wallpaper, samsung-galaxy-s7

Since a few days the wallpaper of my Samsung Galaxy S7 is getting blurred after i use it for a while (10 minutes to an hour).

i just select a picture, tried 5 different ones, (even the stock wallpaper) and after selecting the wallpaper it looks perfect and as it is supposed to be.

then after not using the phone for a few minutes and i unlock it again or after a reboot the wallpaper looks totally blurry.

i haven't installed any apps the past days before this started happening. anyone got an idea what is wrong?

extra info:

- using the default Samsung Launcher. tried Nova launcher same problem.
- used multiple apps to set the wallpaper (using settings of the launcher and using Google wallpapers app both same effect)

Comment: @MukulKumar I have an S7, and I don't see that happen.

Comment: seeing a few replies yesterday that people had the same problem (as answers which were deleted now) i think it has to do with an update of some kind but i don't know which app. also found this: someone with a Nexus 6 having the same problem: http://forums.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-6/749210-wallpaper-periodically-blurring.html so it doesn't seem to be Samsung related

Comment: @GeertvdC try a different launcher, please.

Comment: @MarkYisri i've seen reports from people using other launchers (and other non samsung devices) having the same problem. I've now changed to Arrow launcher to see if this is helping. i'll let you know if it still happens.

Comment: @MarkYisri tried arrow launcher and same thing happens.. so no luck :( any other ideas? one other thing I noticed was it keeps blurring my blurred image. so every few hours the image is blurred more.

Answer (score 2):

I personally don't have this issue, but this is how I solved a friend's phone with this problem:

1. On your phone, go to Google Play and install the [app Muzei](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.nurik.roman.muzei&hl=en)
2. Once installed, tap the open button in the Google Play app. You will be greeted with a splash page with a button that says "activate". Tap the button, and then click set wallpaper at the bottom of the screen.
3. Now you will see a new screen telling you to double-tap your wallpaper to see it in detail. There will also be an icon near the middle of the screen. Tap the icon.
4. At the bottom-right corner of the screen, tap the three dots, and then in the new menu tap customize.
5. Drag left to reveal an option reading "my photos". Tap it.
6. After tapping it, a small settings icon appears under it. Tap it.
7. At the bottom of the screen, tap the "+" button under the text reading "Choose specific photos instead".
8. It will then open the documents app. to get to your photos you can tap the button at the top-left corner of the screen, revealing a new menu. In this menu, tap gallery. Now you can choose one of your photos (or multiple photos).
9. After choosing a photo, tap the back button at the top-left corner of the screen. You should see the screen you saw in step 5.
10. Now tap the text at the top of the screen reading "Sources", and in the new menu that appears tap "advanced".
11. You will now see sliders labeled, "blur", "dim", and "grey". For a completely clear image, drag all of them completely to the left, but you can set these however you want. You should uncheck "apply blur on lockscreen" and you may also want to uncheck "New Wallpaper Notifications".
12. Tap the check mark at the top-left corner of the screen. Now you can close the app and go home to see your clear image.

With this method, you are also able to adjust the brightness of the image by opening the app and following steps 4 and 10-12 in that order. To change the image later open the app and follow steps 4-9 and 12 in that order.

If there are any more issues, I am very happy to help.

Comment: I don't have this issue, but I can approve this solution. Based on my research, this approach seems to be suggested in many forums too. Basically, the trick is to use "static" live wallpaper (like this app), so that the OS doesn't tinkle with it.