# Moto X4 lock screen blurry wallpaper

Tags: moto-x4

When I set a wallpaper on the lock screen with Moto Display on (by default), the wallpaper is blurred when there are any notifications.  I turned Moto Display off and it stopped blurring, but now it's started again, and I don't know how to disable it, since Moto Display is still off.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what's the resolution of image? Moto display pop-up with black screen only no wallpaper shown during pop-up notifications.

Comment: @RahulGopi:  The image shows clearly when there are no notifications, so not sure why the resolution of the image would matter, but it's 0.3 MP and 500 x 690, if that answers the question.

Comment: screen resolution of  device is 1920x1080. if resolution is lower it will affect clarity.

Comment: @RahulGopi: This isn't a matter of normal clarity, though - the picture is fine normally, but it is intentionally blurred by the system when there are notifications.

Comment: I also had moto x4, only added wallpapers of resolution 1080 and higher. If less than 1080, the wallpaper on screen have several shades of light intensity.

Comment: @RahulGopi:  But, again, the wallpaper is fine when there are no notifications.  This is an intentional addition of a blurring effect by the system.

Comment: @RahulGopi:  To demonstrate my point, I set the lock screen wallpaper back to the default one that comes with the device.  It has the **extreme blurring effect** when there is a notification.

Comment: Add some pictures, it'll be helpful to clearly understand the extent of blurring

Comment: @beeshyams:  I don't see Moto Display installed.  Is there another name?  I can see the image fine through Photos.

Comment: @surajck:  I went to take pictures and it appears to be working correctly now.. If it happens again, I will come back with images and more details on which notifications are up.

Comment: Also see if the solution here helps https://android.stackexchange.com/a/166782/131553

Comment: I think the solution suggested above would help (look at the comment below that solution)but they're hasn't been any revert on this from you